# Get octal value when n bits set

Tags: c++, bitset

I want to create a method in C++ which will take a number as parameter. The method should return a number which represents an octal  value for that number of bits set.

Example: If I pass 4 as parameter then the function should return 17 because for bits set to true (1111) = 17. Similarly, when I pass 5 as parameter then the function should return 37 as (11111) = 37. 77 for 6 as parameter and so on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is probably a homework dump.

Comment: Your example shows that the result is octets, not HEX.

Comment: Search the web for "bit twiddling functions".

Comment: @acw1668 Do you mean 'octal'?

Comment: @EJP yes octal number

Comment: @acw1668 Well that isn't the same thing as 'octets'. That's just RFC-speak for 8-bit bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the the left-shift operator and the fact that 2^(n)-1 is a bit string of n-1 1s.

```
unsigned long long HexFunc(unsigned long long val)
{
   return (1 << val) - 1;
}
```

This works because the left-shift operator for integers is equivalent to multiplying an integer by two (assuming no round off occurs). Thus 1 << val is essentially 2^(n).

Comment: @user3139890 No problem, if this answered your question please accept my answer :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The method should return a number which represents a hex value for that number of bits set.

The problem is ambiguous as stated. Many numbers have the same number of bits set.

> Example: If I pass 4 as parameter then the function should return 17 because for bits set to true (1111) = 17.

No it isn't, it's 15, but 30 would also satisfy the requirement (11110), and so would 60, 120, ..., and also various numbers of binary form `10101010`, `01010101`, `110011`, etc.

> Similarly, when I pass 5 as parameter then the function should return 37 as (11111) = 37.

No it doesn't. 11111 is 31.

> 77 for 6 as parameter

Wrong again, it's 63.

> and so on.

The problem is ambiguous as stated. Either you've left something out or it needs to be clarified at source.

And you haven't got one single binary->decimal conversion right. You need to review that. Or are you talking in octal?